# CASE statement plus modulo (%)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

AIM: simple program; when my variable is divided into 3 it returns the word'hip', when it is divided into 5 it returns 'hop' and when it is divided into 3 & 5 at the same time it returns both words.

```
DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
SET @Zmienna = 0

WHILE @Zmienna < 999
BEGIN
    PRINT @Zmienna +
        CASE
            WHEN @Zmienna/3=% THEN ' hip'
            WHEN @Zmienna/5=% THEN ' hop'
        END 
    SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
END
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this schoolwork? Anyway, the modulo operator is `%`, not `/`. To check whether the modulo is 0 you need to write `@Zmienna%3 = 0`

Answer (score 7):

I would use the remainder of the modulo (like you tried) and concatenate the two case statements (else you will never get `hiphop` if both conditions are true). Also you need the `else ''` since otherwise you can get `null` values:

```
CASE
WHEN @Zmienna % 3 = 0
THEN ' hip'
ELSE ''
END
+
CASE
WHEN @Zmienna % 5 = 0
THEN ' hop'
ELSE ''
END
```

Hint: if you want a space or some other text if both conditions are `true`, you have to use an `and` in the case statement:

```
CASE
WHEN @Zmienna % 3 = 0 and @Zmienna % 5 = 0
THEN ' hip hop'
WHEN @Zmienna % 3 = 0
THEN ' hip'
WHEN @Zmienna % 5 = 0
THEN ' hop'
END
```

Comment: To cover the case where both checks are correct just put `WHEN (@Zmienna % 3=0 AND @Zmienna % 5 = 0)` before the other cases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That is a good suggestion. This would be the case if you need `hip(space)hop`. It is not necessary if you just want `hiphop`.

Comment: The OP didn't mention he wants `hiphop`. The explicit case is cleaner, easier to maintain and doesn't require a separate `CASE`. If this indeed schoolwork (as I suspect), the two `CASE` statements will likely be rejected

Comment: Googling for `@ZMienna`, `modulo` makes me suspect this is homework for a Polish university. We are making the OP no favors by answering, but multiple `CASE` and the `ELSE` check would fail, as the point of the exercise is to demonstrate understanding of operators and the `WHEN` statement. I would give extra marks if the OP posted an *additional* solution that *didn't`* require iteration, eg using a numbers table, explaining why it is superior to iteration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I hope for him his professor doesn't know SO :) . I would google every assignment at the end of the semester if I was him.

Comment: @user: need more help?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
SET @Zmienna = 0

WHILE @Zmienna < 999
BEGIN
    PRINT CAST(@Zmienna as varchar) +
        CASE
            when (@Zmienna%3=0 AND @Zmienna%5=0)  THEN ' hip hop'
            WHEN @Zmienna%3=0 THEN ' hip'
            WHEN @Zmienna%5=0 THEN ' hop'

        END 
    SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
END
```

Comment: This will print 'hip' or 'hop' but it won't print both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will give you only 1 dataset instead of 999 for better performance and readability.

Print can only handle 1 value, instead you can SELECT all the rows in 1 go and display the values in different columns instead of concatinating them:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 0 Zmienna
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Zmienna + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Zmienna < 998 -- i wonder why you don't want to include 999
)
SELECT 
  Zmienna,
  CASE
    WHEN Zmienna % 15 = 0 THEN 'hiphop'
    WHEN Zmienna % 3 = 0 THEN 'hip'
    WHEN Zmienna % 5 = 0 THEN 'hop'
  END as Hippityhop
FROM CTE
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: If this is homework, the OP would have to explain the solution and its benefits.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos asking for help for homework could be better, so the teacher doesn't teach you bad habits. But i agree it should be tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `IF` statement

```
    DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
SET @Zmienna = 0

WHILE @Zmienna < 999
BEGIN
    if (@Zmienna % 3) = 0 and (@Zmienna % 5) = 0
BEGIN
PRINT  convert(varchar(10),@Zmienna)+ ' hip'+' '+'hop' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
if (@Zmienna % 3) = 0
BEGIN
PRINT  convert(varchar(10),@Zmienna)+' hip' 
END
if (@Zmienna % 5) = 0
BEGIN
select convert(varchar(10),@Zmienna)+' hop'
END
END
    SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
END
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The iteration is missing and multiple `IF`s aren't an improvement over `CASE` anyway

Comment: fixed it.you can try it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest answer:

DECLARE @Zmienna AS INT
SET @Zmienna = 0

WHILE @Zmienna < 999
BEGIN
    PRINT CAST(@Zmienna as varchar) +
        CASE
            when (@Zmienna%3=0 AND @Zmienna%5=0)  THEN ' hip hop'
            WHEN @Zmienna%3=0 THEN ' hip'
            WHEN @Zmienna%5=0 THEN ' hop'
            ELSE ''

```
    END 
SET @Zmienna = @Zmienna + 1
```

END